# JS and JQuery script conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am experiencing issues when implementing two sets of code for two functions on a webpage I am designing.  I am rather new to JS and JQuery, but none of the similar threads lead to a solution.

On my webpage I have a series of 100vh slideshows (code below) as well as one fullpage "welcome"screen above them.  To transition between them, I am using [a package](http://www.dominikgorecki.com/download/block-scroll/) that offers block scrolling.

Here is my code:

```
// Slideshow code, help from w3schools
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex, show);

function plusDivs(n, show) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n, show);
}

function showDivs(n, show) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"+show);
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "inline";
}


// blockScroller code from the docs on the linked package.
$(function() {
    var blockScroller = $("#main-wrap").blockScroll();
});
```

I can, depending on which block of code is physically higher up in the script, get one of them to work at a time.  However, when the block scrolling works, the slideshow breaks and none of that javascript has any effect on the page. This should tell you that for the sake of each individual scripts, all HTML and CSS requirements are met.

Any help to resolve this conflict would be great, and since this is my first question on stackoverflow if I butchered anything about location or related just tell me. If there is any more information I can provide I will gladly do so.

Here is a sampler of what I am talking about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!--style>
        .slideshow{
            z-index: 500;
            position: relative;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            margin:auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .slideshow > p{
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .mySlides1,.mySlides2{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: center center;
        }


        .slides_button{
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
            padding:8px 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .slides_button:hover{
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        .display_left{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50%;
            left: 0%;
        }

        .display_right{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50%;
            right: 0;
        }
    </style-->


</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="SCRIPT HERE"></script>        <script>  

$(function () {
var blockScroller = $("#main-wrap").blockScroll();


    $(function () {    
    function showDivs(n, show) {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"+show);
            if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1};
            if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length};
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
               x[i].style.display = "none";
            };
            x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
            console.log(x[slideIndex-1])
        };
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showDivs(2, 1);
        showDivs(2, 2);
        $(function () {
        function plusDivs(n, show) {
            showDivs(slideIndex += n, show);
        };
})
         });
       });
    </script>
    <div id="main-wrap">
        <div style="height:100vh;background-image:url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/518164-backgrounds.jpg)">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow">
            <p>slideshow 1</p>
            <img class="mySlides1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/31/00/43/background-texture-1014963_960_720.jpg">
            <button class="slides_button display_left" onclick="plusDivs(-1,1)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="slides_button display_right" onclick="plusDivs(1,1)">&#10095;</button>
            <img class="mySlides1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/orange-geometric-background-with-halftone-dots_1035-7243.jpg">
            <img class="mySlides1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/31/00/43/background-texture-1014963_960_720.jpg">
            <img class="mySlides1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/orange-geometric-background-with-halftone-dots_1035-7243.jpg">

        </div>
        <div class="slideshow">
            <p>slideshow 2</p>
            <img class="mySlides2" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-87.jpg">
            <button class="slides_button display_left" onclick="plusDivs(-1,2)">&#10094;</button>
            <button class="slides_button display_right" onclick="plusDivs(1,2)">&#10095;</button>
            <img class="mySlides2" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/flower_pink_background_vector_art_148632.jpg">
            <img class="mySlides2" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/clouds_in_sky_background_192377.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[blockerScoll js script](https://github.com/DominikGorecki/block-scroll/blob/master/js/blockScroll.js)

Comment: any errors? any weird behaviour?

Comment: No errors from what I can tell, and when the block scrolling works, all the images in the slideshow display one after the other, making the page super long.

Comment: So this is rather a CSS interference... :/ ( which is more hard to debug). Probably the best and easiest6 solution would be writing it from the ground up. Then you notice where it fails.

Comment: You can debug each code lines with `console.log()` so maybe make sure all variable values meet your expectation.

Comment: I can provide more code and information if you need it.  I've been toying with this all morning

Comment: @JulienLuebbers Then try to create a minimal runnable example and provide it.

Comment: @reporter I made one for you, and put it at the bottom but I left open how to link in the blockScroll package since I dont know how to attach that and uploading 250 extra lines seems maybe not the best.

Comment: @reporter the updated example is without css now.  Should be even more minimal (I still haven't been able to find the issue)

Comment: At my first look on your code, there are two horrible mistakes in your code. First: You try to look for an element wich is crated later and you mixed jquery and plain javascript in an incompatible way.

Comment: @reporter I think I fixed the first issue because of the answer provided below, but what about my script is incompatible? (Seriously new to this so I didn't know this could happen)

Comment: @JulienLuebbers Your script is not incompatible. Jquery objects and objects of plain javascript are sometimes incompatible. As @ewwink it did I removed `$(function () {});`from your plain javascript methods either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not work because `show` in `showDivs(slideIndex, show);` is undefined, it should be like this

```
showDivs(slideIndex, 1);
showDivs(slideIndex, 2);
```

demo

```js
//This is only for the block scrolling.  If you move this 
//ABOVE the  previous section, then it will take over.
$(function() {
  var blockScroller = $("#main-wrap").blockScroll();
});

//This is the slideshow section.  Move this above the block scroll
//and this works.
function showDivs(n, show) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides" + show);
  if(n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if(n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
    
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline";
  //console.log(x[slideIndex - 1])
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex, 1);
showDivs(slideIndex, 2);

function plusDivs(n, show) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n, show);
}
```

```css
.slideshow {
  z-index: 500;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow>p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

.mySlides1,
.mySlides2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}

.slides_button {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}

.slides_button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.display_left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0%;
}

.display_right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.dominikgorecki.com/p/block-scroll/blockScroll.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//www.dominikgorecki.com/p/block-scroll/js/blockScroll.js"></script>
   
<div id="main-wrap">
  <div style="height:100vh;background-image:url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/518164-backgrounds.jpg)">
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow">
    <p>slideshow 1</p>
    <img class="mySlides1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/31/00/43/background-texture-1014963_960_720.jpg">
    <button class="slides_button display_left" onclick="plusDivs(-1,1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="slides_button display_right" onclick="plusDivs(1,1)">&#10095;</button>
    <img class="mySlides1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/orange-geometric-background-with-halftone-dots_1035-7243.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/31/00/43/background-texture-1014963_960_720.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides1" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/orange-geometric-background-with-halftone-dots_1035-7243.jpg">
  </div>
    
  <div class="slideshow">
    <p>slideshow 2</p>
    <img class="mySlides2" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-87.jpg">
    <button class="slides_button display_left" onclick="plusDivs(-1,2)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="slides_button display_right" onclick="plusDivs(1,2)">&#10095;</button>
    <img class="mySlides2" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/flower_pink_background_vector_art_148632.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides2" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/clouds_in_sky_background_192377.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I ran your demo and the slideshow worked but the block scrolling didn't.  I also toyed with it offline and couldn't get this to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: updated the code, scrolling didn't work because `blockScroll.js` not loaded, mixed content `http` and `https`

Comment: That looks beautiful and perfect in the stackoverflow code runner but I can't get it to work offline (I use brackets) or on an actual site. Its kinda weird...